# Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API - Universe of metric data types

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the [Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime) and writing a function to map the string `columnHeaders.dataType` to a `Type`. The documentation states the following:

> Data type. Dimension column headers have only STRING as the data type. Metric column headers have data types for metric values such as INTEGER, DOUBLE, CURRENCY etc.

I'm wondering if anyone can document a definitive definition of the *etc* for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) returns all the Dimension and Metrics with their attributes in JSON format.

Checkout [Live Metadata API response](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1), in which you will be able to find all the data types.

List of data types for Dimensions:

- STRING

List of data types for Metrics:

- INTEGER
- PERCENT
- TIME
- CURRENCY
- FLOAT